# How psycopg2 from Notebook connects to psql terminal?

Tags: postgresql, shell, psycopg2, psql

I am a new baby to postgresql and I just have a chance to practice psycopg2. 
This is the code I used for psycopg2 to connect to the db somewhere (I don't know)

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(host="localhost",port=5432, dbname="a1", user="god")
```

And this is what my databases from **psql** terminal look like

```
                         List of databases
   Name    | Owner | Encoding | Collate | Ctype | Access privileges 
-----------+-------+----------+---------+-------+-------------------
 a1        | god   | UTF8     | C       | C     | 
 postgres  | god   | UTF8     | C       | C     | 
 template0 | god   | UTF8     | C       | C     | =c/god           +
           |       |          |         |       | god=CTc/god
 template1 | god   | UTF8     | C       | C     | =c/god           +
           |       |          |         |       | god=CTc/god
 x         | god   | UTF8     | C       | C     |
```

As you can see, database a1 is listed (If a1 was not created from **psql**, the psycopg2 code would complain "db a1 not exist") 
**Then I selected databse a1 as my current databse (\c a1)**
And then I used "below" to execute the command from Jupyter Notebook to add table student to a1

```
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("""
    CREATE TABLE Student(
    SID integer PRIMARY KEY,
    Name text,
)""")
```

And the **psql** terminal was showing

```
2021-02-08 00:08:14.597 EST [71497] STATEMENT:  
        CREATE TABLE Student(
        SID integer PRIMARY KEY,
        Name text,
    )
```

However, when I pressed **Enter**, and did **\dt**, it was telling me that **Did not find any relations.**

```
a1=# \dt
Did not find any relations.
```

I thought I was connected to a1 but seemed like psycopg2 was not connected to the database a1 in **psql** and therefore the Student table was not added ? Or am I missing something important ? 
Any feedbacks or comments is appreciated !

Comment: You need to commit: `conn.commit()`

Comment: `psql` was not showing you that log message.  You appear to have your server's log just spewing to the same terminal in which you are running `psql`, so the output streams get jumbled up.  You should probably have your server log to a file, or at least to a different terminal than the one you use to run `psql`.  That is one part of the puzzle.  The other part is as Maurice said.

Comment: Provided `create table` statement is invalid because of comma after the last column declaration. Or it is just the piece of the real query?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to commit when executing a query in `psycopg2`

You can add the following line after you connection object to set it to autocommit. `conn.set_session(autocommit=True)`